# Trying to upload the latest plugin for Google Cloud to Data Fusion but getting an error while uploading

Tags: maven, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Reference to this post that I had earlier: [Possible to modify or delete rows from a table in BigQuery dataset with a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697074/possible-to-modify-or-delete-rows-from-a-table-in-bigquery-dataset-with-a-cloud) I am trying to do the suggested answer to compile the latest version of Google Cloud Platform plugin and upload to Data Fusion so I can use the latest features.

We have downloaded the code, compiled it and got 2 files:

- google-cloud-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- google-cloud-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT.json

Inside the JSON file, the last lines for the parent artifacts were:

```
  },
  "parents": [
    "system:cdap-data-pipeline[6.1.0-SNAPSHOT,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)",
    "system:cdap-data-streams[6.1.0-SNAPSHOT,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)"
  ]
}
```

Initially I went to Data Fusion and choose to upload a new plugin, but I got an error about the parent artifacts not existing. So I did some digging and found out the version of used artifacts on Data Fusion currently to be 6.0.1:
[image]

So I modified the parent artifacts to the correct versions, and now the last few lines in the JSON file show:

```
  },
  "parents": [
    "system:cdap-data-pipeline[6.0.1-SNAPSHOT,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)",
    "system:cdap-data-streams[6.0.1-SNAPSHOT,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)"
  ]
}
```

When I try to upload the plugin again, it seems to pass the artifacts check step, but it fails on some sort of a class check and I see this in the upload screen:
[image]

> Class could not be found while inspecting artifact for plugins. Please
>   check dependencies are available, and that the correct parent artifact
>   was specified. Error class: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError,
>   message: io/cdap/cdap/etl/api/validation/ValidationException.

So now I'm really lost about what's wrong here. I'm doubting that the artifacts version that is being used in Data Fusion does not have the class that is throwing the error? If so, how do I update the artifact itself?

Or if there is something else that I am missing in this whole process, then I would really appreciate any guidance or support on this!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the release/0.12 branch of the google-cloud plugins repo. That is compatible with the 6.0 version of Cloud Data Fusion.